# Why does openFile with WriteMode truncate the file? How not to?

Tags: haskell

Haskell's `openFile` has this tidbit in the source:

```
-- we want to truncate() if this is an open in WriteMode, but only
-- if the target is a RegularFile.  ftruncate() fails on special files
-- like /dev/null.
when (iomode == WriteMode && fd_type == RegularFile) $
  setSize fD 0
```

This was very surprising, I assumed that the `IOMode`s were merely wrappers around `O_WRONLY`, `O_RDONLY` and `O_RDWR`. Why is this the case? How does one open a file for write only without truncating?

Comment: Yes, that's what `O_WRONLY` means. The distinction between opening a file for writing and opening a file for appending predates Haskell by quite a bit, and is defined at a lower level than any one programming language's semantics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `IOMode` was designed like the `mode` argument in the `fopen` function.

From `man fopen`:

> w - Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

If you wanna to open a file for writing only (without truncate it) then you wanna append it usually. So just use `AppendMode`. If you don't wanna to have position on the end of a file (also you don't wanna to have position on the begin of a file usually) you can use the `hSeek` to change it.

Comment: That seems legitimate. Interestingly there's no way to fopen write only without truncating either.

Answer (score 1):

IO modes `AppendMode` or `ReadWriteMode` should open the file for writing without truncating it.

Comment: Yes but ReadWriteMode requires read permissions. I only want to write.